# Format array in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I was wondering if it's possible to print an array into a textarea and after every 4th row (in array or textarea) place a linebreak or something like `-----`.

In below example I have some input fioelds inside a form which need to be placed in a textarea. Afterwards this textarea is submitted. 'The reason for this is that I use a SaaS platform so I need to work around this problem.

So what I have is this:

```
  $('.req').on('click', function(){

  var data = [];
  $('.table input').each(function() {
    data.push($(this).val());
  });

  var textarea = document.getElementById("form-message");
  textarea.value = data.join("\n");

  });
```

As a result I get

```
21546
Some name
150
12345
Some name
555
54646
Some name
578
```

How can I print it out like this:

```
21546
Some name
150
----------------
12345
Some name
555
----------------
54646
Some name
578
```

Is that even possible?

Thx in advance for any assistence :)

Comment: Please include the appropriate HTML in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick solution

```
   $('.req').on('click', function(){

      var data = [];
      $('.table input').each(function(index) {        
        data.push($(this).val());
        if((index+1)%3===0) {
          data.push("-----------------");
        }
      });

      var textarea = document.getElementById("form-message");
      textarea.value = data.join("\n");

    });
```

Using the index value returned by `.each()` and the modulo in `if((index+1)%3 === 0)`, you can very easily add an additional entry every three lines. Use %n to do it every n lines.

Here is a fiddle showing the solution : 
https://jsfiddle.net/055074yu/

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be:

```
$('.table input').each(function() {
  data.push($(this).val());
  if ((data.length + 1) % 4 === 0) {
    data.push('----------------');
  }
});
```

Ok, I've finally made the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jordinebot/Lmgzpmp0/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/xxz8jvp1/#&togetherjs=4Omvir70QG). it may help!

JS:

```
$('.req').on('click', function(){

  var data = [];
  $('.table.input').each(function(i) {
  if((i+1)%3)
  data.push($(this).val());  
  else
  {
   data.push($(this).val());
   data.push("-------------");
  }
  });

  var textarea = document.getElementById("form-message");
  textarea.value = data.join("\n");

  });
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<textarea id="form-message"></textarea>
</div>

<input type="text" class="table input"/>
<input type="text" class="table input"/>
<input type="text" class="table input"/>
<input type="text" class="table input"/>
<input type="text" class="table input"/>
<input type="text" class="table input"/>
<input class="req" type="button" value="button"/>
```